# Why can't a string literal be assigned to variable of type String

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion, typeerror, scala-3

I'm trying out Scala 3, and try to assign a string literal to a variable in the console. If I don't give it an explicit type, everything is fine:

```
scala> val s = "hello"
val s: String = hello
```

And the variable even has the type `String` inferred. When I make the type explicit, however, I get a type error:

```
scala> val t: String = "hello"
1 |val t: String = "hello"
  |                ^^^^^^^
  |                Found:    ("hello" : String)
  |                Required: String
```

The same happens when I make a `var` with explicit type:

```
scala> var v: String = _
var v: String = null

scala> v = "hello"
1 |v = "hello"
  |    ^^^^^^^
  |    Found:    ("hello" : String)
  |    Required: String
```

However if I initialise the `var` with a string literal, I can assign other string literals to it:

```
scala> var u = "hello"
var u: String = hello

scala> u = "world"
u: String = world
```

What's the type system secret behind some string variables being allowed to hold string literals, while others aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: I had defined a case class named `String` in my package that overshadowed `java.lang.String`. But the error messages didn't include the FQCN, leading to confusion.

Comment: The error messages really should state that the two `String` types in question are different. Perhaps you could make a feature request, since this would probably help other people too.